# pandas dataframe subtraction result has row and dtype information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe and I compute a very simple subtraction like so:

```
p0_cost =  cost_df['price1'][cost_df['date']==p0] - \
            cost_df['price2'][cost_df['date']==p0]
```

I compute various other statistics in addition to `p0_cost`. I save these statistics into a `dict()` structure which I then use to create a dataframe.

Now, what happens is the value of `p0_cost` looks like:

```
12 213.151824 dtype: float64
```

The actual value `213.151824` but it also saves the row and `dtype` information.

How do I just get the value and not all this other junk?

Comment: If you want just the scalar then subscript the array using `.values[0]`: `cost_df['price1'][cost_df['date']==p0].values[0]`

Comment: Thank you. That works great. But it is strange that subtracting dataframes comes with all the other information.

Comment: Well it depends on the use case, here you're populating a dict so you're storing the result which in this case is a `Series` this is by design. Pandas expects you to perform arithmetic ops between compatible types, once you store the returned types in a container and then try to make a df from this, you're going to run into problems because the df will try to use the existing index and names/columns in your dict values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a dict with the values of `Series`, if you want just the scalar value then subscript into the results using `.values[0]`:

```
p0_cost =  (cost_df['price1'][cost_df['date']==p0] - cost_df['price2'][cost_df['date']==p0]).values[0]
```