# extract datetime obj value from pandas Series (single row)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have same issue as describe here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022862/pandas-dataframe-subtraction-result-has-row-and-dtype-information) but this time with a datetime object.

Using .values converts the datetime object to something like `2011-02-28T19:00:00.000000000-0500`.

Prior to the conversion the datetime was `2011-03-01`

What is the proper way to do what I want to do?

Comment: If needed you can call `date` prior to `.values` should work, e.g. `p0_cost =  (cost_df['price1'][cost_df['date']==p0] - cost_df['price2'][cost_df['date']==p0]).dt.date.values[0]`

Comment: You are amazing! This works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the high precision of the datetime64[ns] values if you're only interested in dates then you can calll `dt.date` prior to calling `.values`:

```
p0_cost = (cost_df['price1'][cost_df['date']==p0] - cost_df['price2'][cost_df['date']==p0]).dt.date.values[0]
```